# How to let ZFS users create their own datasets?

Tags: permissions, zfs, snapshot

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 in a VM, and I have followed the instructions [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/setup-zfs-storage-pool#1-overview) for creating a ZFS pool.

However, the commands to create, mount and unmount zfs datasets all appear to require root. I would like to create a specific pool in which users are allowed to create and delete their own datasets.

I have read that I should be able to do this to give a user permissions:

```
sudo zfs create new-pool/userspace # this works
sudo zfs allow $USER create,mount,unmount new-pool/userspace # this fails
```

I get the error:

```
cannot set permissions on 'new-pool/userspace': operation not applicable to datasets of this type
```

Originally ZFS on Linux (ZoL) didn't support `allow`, but apparently it was added in 0.7.0 so I believe it is expected to work. How do I resolve this?

Other potentially relevant info:

```
$ zfs get type new-pool/userspace
NAME                PROPERTY  VALUE       SOURCE
new-pool/userspace  type      filesystem  -
$ zfs list
NAME                 USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
new-pool            6.44G  12.4G     6.44G  /new-pool
new-pool/userspace    24K  12.4G       24K  /new-pool/userspace
$ ls -ld /new-pool/userspace
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 2 Nov  4 19:31 /new-pool/userspace
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a misleading error message. The problem is that `unmount` is not a valid permission. `create` and `mount` both work. There is an open issue to make the error message better [here](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/11903).